# python MULTILINE re.findall spliting on one blank line

Tags: python, regex

I have a regular expression that succeeds if the input has 2 blank lines between the string sections that I want to separate. But it fails if there is only one blank line.  Can you advise?

I'm scanning a big folder of files for class definitions. Here's an example that works as intended, it notices 2 classes and separates them.

```
classstr = """class friendly():
    def __init__(x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def printme(): 
        print(self.x)


class unfriendly():
    def friendme():
        assert self.x == self.y
"""
y = re.findall(r'^(class\s.*)((?:\n^\s.+)+)', classstr, re.MULTILINE)
```

The output is a list with two tuples, one for each class.

```
In [15]: y
Out[15]: 
[('class friendly():',
  '\n    def __init__(x, y, z):\n        self.x = x\n        self.y = y\n        self.z = z'),
 ('class unfriendly():',
  '\n    def friendme():\n        assert self.x == self.y')]
```

If the input `classstr` is changed to have only one blank row between the classes (as often is the case in example code), then the whole code block comes back in one blob tuple:

```
[('class friendly():',
  '\n    def __init__(x, y, z):\n        self.x = x\n        self.y = y\n        self.z = z\n\n    def printme():\n        print(self.x)\n\nclass unfriendly():\n    def friendme():\n        assert self.x == self.y')]
```

I cannot understand how to terminate the re on a single blank line, apparently.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things to note:

- Using `\s` can also match a newline
- In your pattern you use `\n^\s.+` Meaning that the next line should contain at least 2 characters, or a newline and a line with at least a single character

If there is 1 empty line in between it will match the next part as `\n` and  `\s` will match the newline, and `.+` will match the rest of the line.

It will not work when there are 2 empty lines, as `\n` will match the first empty line, `\s` will then match the the second newline but the `.+` can not match as the line is empty.

What you could do, is match all lines that do not start with `class`  and make the quantifier for the whole line `*` to also match empty lines in between.

```
^(class[^\S\n].*)((?:\n(?!class ).*)+)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `class[^\S\n].*` match class followed by a whitespace char without a newline and the rest of the line
- `)` Close group 1
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `(?:` Non capture group (to repeat as a whole)

    - `\n(?!class ).*` Match a newline and assert that the line does not start with `class`
  - `)+` Close the non capture group and repeat at least 1+ times
- `)` Close group 2

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pRnzjF/1)

Comment: The demo on regex101 puts this answer in the "above and beyond" category.  Anybody who is interested should look at that after studying the explanation here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a little trouble in applying the accepted answer. The solution did solve the problem as I presented it, but in practice the files I'm sifting through include other code besides classes.  So if there was a `def` following a class, the given code would include the function definition within the output for the preceeding class (because the re` was looking literally for lines taht started with anything except "class" to determine inclusion).

For example, the `re` gobbled in the `def amorous` here:

```
classstr = """class friendly():
    def __init__(x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def printme():
        print(self.x)


class unfriendly():
    def friendme():
        assert self.x == self.y

def amorous():
    x = 3
"""
```

I to avoid that, I adjusted the `re` in the solution to include all new lines that do not begin with a character, rather than including all lines that do not begin literally with "class".

```
y = re.findall(r'^(class[^\S\n].*)((?:\n(?!\S+).*)+)', classstr,
                   re.MULTILINE)
y2 = ["".join(i) for i in y]
```

And the output is good, at least for this example.

```
>>> pprint(y2, compact=True)
['class friendly():\n'
 '    def __init__(x, y, '
 'z):\n'
 '        self.x = x\n'
 '        self.y = y\n'
 '        self.z = z\n'
 '\n'
 '    def printme():\n'
 '        print(self.x)\n'
 '\n',
 'class unfriendly():\n'
 '    def friendme():\n'
 '        assert self.x == self.y\n']
```

I'm waiting to see what other bad-effects this revision causes :)

Meanwhile, I have found some other benefits from this change.  Using similar `re` to separate `def` function declarations works fine, even for nested functions.